# ¿Cómo hacer una función que filtre números positivos? Java

Tags: java, filtro, números-enteros

Necesito que el método `dameSoloPositivos` me devuelva un `array` de longitud igual a tantos números positivos como haya.

Tengo el método `contarNegativos`, que me dice cuántos números negativos hay en el `array`:

```
public static int contarNegativos(int [] arr){
  int resultado = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] < 0){
      resultado++;
    }
  }
  return resultado;
}
```

Y este es el método pero no consigo que me funcione del todo:

```
static int[] dameSoloPositivos (int[] arr){
  int[] aux=new int[arr.length-contarNegativos(arr)];
  int j = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] >= 0){
      aux[j]=aux[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  return aux;
}
```

Por ejemplo:

- Dado el `arr={-1}` devuelva `{}`.
- Dado el `arr={1,-2,-5,6}` devuelva `{1,6}`.
- Dado el `arr={2}` devuelva `{2}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno podria mostrarte códigos para optimizar el tuyo pero voy a enfocarme en mostrarte donde se encuentra tu error:

```
if(arr[i] >= 0){
    aux[j]=aux[i]; // Exactamente aqui esta el error
    j++;
}
```

estas igualando `aux = aux` lo que deberia ser `aux = arr` de la siguiente forma:

```
if(arr[i] >= 0){
    aux[j]=arr[i];
    j++;
}
```

Espero te funcione ;) Saludos

Comment: Gracias!!, que fallo mas tonto

Comment: No te preocupes a todos nos paso algo así alguna vez XDXD.

Answer (score 1):

Cuenta solo los positivos así evitas la resta, agrégalos a una lista y posteriormente usa el metodo `intList.toArray(intArray)`

```
static int[] dameSoloPositivos (int[] arr){
List<Integer> positivos = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if( arr[i] > 0 ) {
            positivos.add(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    int[] arr_positivos = positivos.toArray(new int[positivos.size()]);
    return arr_positivos;
}
```